# ¿Cómo cambiar la fuente de letra en LibGDX?

Tags: libgdx, fuentes

Estoy haciendo un videojuego y necesito poner texto "GAME OVER" por ejemplo. He conseguido poner el texto en pantalla pero la fuente de letra es la por defecto de LibGDX y quiero cambiarla pero al intentar cambiarla usando

`font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("Chocolate_DRINK_DEMO.ttf"))`

me da el error " Error loading font file".   Este es el código de la clase que uso para poner texto en pantalla:

```
BitmapFont font;
GlyphLayout glyphLayout;
String text;

float x;
float y;


public ScreenText(float x, float y) {


    font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("Chocolate_DRINK_DEMO.ttf"));
    font.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    font.getData().setScale(10);

    glyphLayout = new GlyphLayout();

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    text = "";
}

public void setText(String text) {

    glyphLayout.setText(font, text);
    this.text = text;
}


public void draw(SpriteBatch batch) {

    font.draw(batch, text, x - glyphLayout.width / 2, y - glyphLayout.height / 2);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La forma más fácil para generar `fonts` `ttf` es utilizando la extensión `freetype` la cual puedes importar marcando la casilla `freetype` al generar el proyecto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si **no** marcaste esta casilla al generar el proyecto tendrás que importarlo manualmente en el `build.gradle`

```
project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        ...
        ...
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
    }
}
```

Creas el generador y lo utilizas para generar fuentes de distintos tamaños o colores.

```
private FreeTypeFontGenerator generator;

public ScreenText(float x, float y) {
    ...
    ...


    generator       = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("Chocolate_DRINK_DEMO.ttf"));


    BitmapFont font = crearFont(12,Color.WHITE);
}

public BitmapFont crearFont(int size,Color color){

    FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
    parameter.size          = size;
    parameter.incremental   = true;
    //Si quieres añadirle un borde
    //parameter.borderColor     = Color.BLACK;
    //parameter.borderWidth     = 0.55f;

    BitmapFont font = generator.generateFont(parameter);

    font.setColor(color);

    font.getRegion().getTexture().setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);
    return font;
}
```

**Notas:**

- Los `BitmapFont`s son `Disposable` y tienes que tienes que disponerlos cuando no los necesites `font.dispose();`
- Para evitar crear tantos `fonts` puedes crearlos de color blanco `Color.WHITE` todos y luego si necesitas otro color y usas un `Label` puedes cambiarle el color `label.getStyle().fontColor = Color.RED` de esta manera si el juego necesitas 3 fonts de distintos tamaños solo tendrias que crear 3 fonts